# Rig legging only spins on z axis. x and y axis also only move on z axis

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, axis

New blender user here.  I've searched multiple sites for a solution to this problem, but I haven't been able find one that solves my issue.  I have attached a video that shows my issue.

https://streamable.com/jhn2rl

1. When I try and move the legs on the x and y axis, they only spin on the z axis.  When I choose z axis, it of course works fine.
2. The rest of the armature works fine as well.

Things tried:

1. Removing any constraints.
2. Unlocking all the location values.
3. Unlocking location checkbox in the tool panel.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: A file would probably be necessary to fully diagnose this.  It's entirely possible that the bone *is* rotating (at least, once you delete the IK, otherwise the IK is limiting the rotation, probably fully limiting it) but that it is not a deforming bone, and that the deforming bone has constraints that prevent it from rotating in that way.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Nathan.

Here is the armature I'm trying to use: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VVNQ_oVLICw1xsyIxab6rOL8LCeiANM-/view?usp=share_link

Here is my world with the armature imported.  It's the one's in front of the big house: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UrIghsXkuTlowRpggZFFJc9asHdFYZWj/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the constraints on all the leg bones (both upper and lower) seems to fix the rotation issue. The problem here is that IK doesn't really work for a chain of only two bones. I'd suggest either using the armature as an FK only or try and see if rigify can make it work.

Comment: Ethan, thank you so much! That did it.